# How to read the displayed value in html form back to Python flask for further processing

Tags: python, flask

`I rendered an HTML form with the table data and it displayed the values and in the same page I am accepting few valaues from the user.When the user presses the submit button, I want the dispalyed value to be passed back to the python flask program for further processing.
For example:
my HTML code as follows..

```
            <p> Stock to Sell      : {{stks[0]}} </p>
            <p> Stock Bought for   : {{stks[1]}} </p>
            <p> Date of Purchase   : {{stks[2]}} </p>
            <p> Target Date        : {{stks[3]}} </p>
            <p> Stop Loss Price    : {{stks[4]}} </p>
            <br></br>
            Enter the Sale Price           :
            <input type="text" name="saleprice">`your text`
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Add">
            </form>
        </div>
```

After the user presses the submit button and when control gets back to program I want to read the value in {{stks[0]}} value in my program.
Please let me know how to do that`

Answer (score 0):

In your python code, get the value in the input with `flask.request.form.get("saleprice")` and edit the stks python list with the new value

```
stks = [4, 5, 8, 1, 2]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        new_saleprice = flask.request.form.get("saleprice")
        stks[0] = new_saleprice
    return flask.render_template('index.html', stks=stks)
```

In your HTML, replace your submit input by a button and don't forget to add `method="POST"` in your form

```
<form method="POST">
    <p> Stock to Sell      : {{stks[0]}} </p>
    <p> Stock Bought for   : {{stks[1]}} </p>
    <p> Date of Purchase   : {{stks[2]}} </p>
    <p> Target Date        : {{stks[3]}} </p>
    <p> Stop Loss Price    : {{stks[4]}} </p>
    <br>
    Enter the Sale Price           :
    <input type="text" name="saleprice">`your text`
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Basically i wanted the send the value in {{stks[0]}} which hascthe value of stock name. I am comfortable with receiving the sale price value in my program